# QMenu item does not react at first click

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qmenu, qaction

I have a problem with the reaction of QMenu items, which I create on a QPushButton.

The action is executed only if I double-click on the menu-item, after that it works also with only one click.

In `guiMain.cxx`, I create a QMenu via signal/slot in the `settingsMenu` class, which has no access to the GUI elements or predefined actions, and emit the created QMenu object back in `guiMain.cxx`.

After emitting the QMenu, I add my predefined actions in it and connect it to another method.

What is wrong with this workflow?

guiMain.cxx:

```cpp
void guiMain::createSignalAndSlots()
{
  connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
  (m_SettingsMenu.data(), SLOT(createViewSettingsMenuSlot()));

  connect(m_SettingsMenu.data(), SIGNAL(getViewSettingsMenuSignal(QMenu *)),
  this, SLOT(getViewSettingsMenuSlot(QMenu *)));
}


void guiMain::getViewSettingsMenuSlot(QMenu *menu)
{
 menu->addAction(actionResetView);

 connect(actionResetView, SIGNAL(triggered()),
         this, SLOT(resetViewsSlot()));
}

void guiMain::(resetViewsSlot()
{
  do something
}
```

settingsMenu.cxx:

```cpp
void settingsMenu::createViewSettingsMenuSlot()
{
  QWidget *widget= new QWidget();

  QWidgetAction *wa= new QWidgetAction(0);
  wa->setDefaultWidget(widget);

  QMenu *menu= new QMenu;
  menu->addAction(wa);

  emit getViewSettingsMenuSignal(menu);
}
```